# SharePoint interact with Rich HTML editor using javascript

Tags: ribbon, richhtmlfield

Is there any way to manipulate the editor content by using JavaScript?
My ultimate goal is to allow user to click a button on ribbon bar, and JS will help to insert some predefined template html into the editor for editing. The whole concept is similar to reusable content, only reusable content is readonly after inserting.

I have no problem in adding the button to ribbon bar, but I cant find anyway to manipulate the HTML content inside the editor.

Thanks in advance.